# Problem with FLTK install on macOS Catalina 10.15.1

Tags: c++, macos, fltk

I installed FLTK version 1.3.5 on macOS Catalina 10.15.1. I used next commands:
configure
make
sudo make install

After last command I have next report:

```
=== installing FL ===
Installing include files in /usr/local/include...
=== installing src ===
Installing libraries in /usr/local/lib...
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(Fl_x.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_dnd.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_overlay_visual.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(fl_call_main.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(scandir.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(keysym2Ucs.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(utf8Input.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(utf8Utils.o) has no symbols
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/ranlib: file: /usr/local/lib/libfltk.a(utf8Wrap.o) has no symbols
=== installing fluid ===
Installing FLUID in /usr/local/bin...
=== installing test ===
Installing example programs to /usr/local/share/doc/fltk/examples...
=== installing documentation ===
Installing documentation files in /usr/local/share/doc/fltk ...
Installing man pages in /usr/local/share/man ...
```

Is it an error? And how I can fix it?

Comment: They don't look like error messages. Homebrew is much easier in the future.

Comment: Have you tried to write&run a program after installing it?